# Neural Network Matlab Parallel GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, neural-network

When training a Neural Network with Matlab, if I use one CPU or a GPU then the GUI that shows how the training is progressing appears to let me know how its doing.

When I run `train(net,inputs,targets,'useParallel','yes');` however i.e. train using multiple CPUs, the GUI no longer appears.

How can I have the GUI open when training with multiple CPUs?

Comment: what if you set the 'showResources' property to 'yes'? Is this what you mean?

Comment: Not quite, I want to see the GUI display that has loading bars moving across it.